# navigating from one php page to other

Tags: php

i made a form in which i input login information....if the information was correct the next page opened else the login form appeared again with 'wrong info' note....for this i wrote the following code in the login.php(form page)...first within php tags i wrote

```
if( isset( $_POST["h11"]))  
{echo "wrong password";}
```

and then below this outside the php tags, within the form tags , i set the value of h11(type hidden) to true...after this i coded the entire login form with action="loginback.php"...now in loginback.php i tested if username and password provided by the user are correct...if not i redirected the page to login.php using `header("location:login.php")`....now my problem is that the message wrong password is not being displayed as when we redirect to login.php from loginback after checking inputted info,the value of isset() becomes 0 again...so plz tell me how can i make this message appear...?

Comment: What does this have to do with phpmyadmin? (as you have added that tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, just add code in login.php to check for $_REQUEST['h11'] instead, and append the querystring in your header code.

loginback.php has

```
header("location:login.php?h11=blah");
```

login.php has

```
if( isset( $_REQUEST["h11"]))
{echo "wrong password";}
```

Comment: @avinash It's the query string. You know $_GET right? It lets you access that.